# When data connection is lost while a call is started on CDMA?

Tags: android, mobile, connection, cdma

I have an application that works while a call is made. Sometimes I need data. If I'm on a device with CDMA network and there is no WiFi I'm loosing the "data" from the network operator. I know that is a CDMA limitation. I just want to know when is happening exactly.
When the connection is made, when the ring is started or when the call is established...or when..

Answer (score 0):

CDMA comes in several flavors.  Assuming your device has a single radio, it comes (basically) in CDMA-1X and EvDO flavors.   CDMA-1X is using the old circuit-switched network to move data around.  Thus, when you start a voice call, you just took away the pipe for the data.  The switches can handle it by "putting your data stream on hold", but you do lose the pipe.
EvDO is more of a packet flow in some ways, but in the end, we still need the circuit.   This is the main benefits of moving from CDMA to LTE.